# Combine data array of different grid size in xarray

Tags: python, python-3.x, multidimensional-array, python-xarray, coordinate-transformation

I would like to combine the two data arrays according to the latlon and select the higher one when duplicated.

The two data arrays are as below:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'Location A' (lat: 1850, lon: 1300)>
array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]])
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float32 22.5 22.49 22.48 22.47 ... 4.03 4.02 4.01
  * lon      (lon) float32 95.0 95.01 95.02 95.03 ... 107.97 107.98 107.99
```

```
<xarray.DataArray 'Location B' (lat: 721, lon: 481)>
array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]])
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float32 24.5 24.475 24.45 24.425 ... 6.575 6.55 6.525 6.5
  * lon      (lon) float32 100.0 100.025 100.05 100.075 ... 111.95 111.975 112.0
```

The two arrays are in different size and spatial resolution (grid size). I have tried `xr.concat` `xr.merge` `xr.combine_first` `xr.combine_by_coords` `xr.combine_nested` to combine them. However, all of them did not work.

So, how can I convert the latlon into the same scale so that I could combine my data?

Comment: You should interpolate one of the arrays, so that it has the same grid as the other. There do not appear to be any latlon match ups, so I think interpolation is your only option.

Answer (score 2):

Robert was right

You can do this:

```py
locB_interp = locB.interp_like(locA)

dset = xr.merge([locA, locB_interp])
```

Hope this helps.